# What is bispectrum?

Tags: emotion, measurement, terminology, eeg, signal-detection

I am working on a project that uses EEG signals of the brain to identify emotional states. While surveying the literature, I came across several references where "derived features of bispectrum" are used as features for the purpose of classifying motor and emotional signals.

Although I have a list of these "derived features" at my disposal, I would like to have some intuition as to which of these features I should use and why consider a bispectrum in the first place. I would highly appreciate it if the physical significance of the bispectrum could be explained in relation to EEG signals.

**What is EEG bispectrum?**

Comment: Welcome to CogSci.SE and thanks for your interesting question! Could you please add a reference or article link describing these derived features of the bispectrum?

Comment: Sure!! [Introduction to bispectrum for EEG analysis](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~davidc/pubs/pgbiomed09.pdf), [Using HOS from EEG signals for developing BCI](https://www.dora.dmu.ac.uk/handle/2086/874) @ChrisStronks

Comment: Thanks. And what exactly is the list, as you ask which of them you should use?

Comment: The list is not central to the question, as there are methods of determining a favorable set of features for classification purposes. What I am not getting is, how the bispectrum of EEG would prove to be a better discriminant than other measures such as features of PSD of EEG. @ChrisStronks

Comment: I don't think it is a matter of better or worse, but to a matter of adding information. FFT results in frequency and phase data. Often the phase (50% of the FFT data in fact) is thrown away without bothering.

Comment: The second page of the paper cited defines exactly what is meant by bispectrum: "The corresponding bispectrum is defined as the 2-D
Fourier transform of the third-order cumulant." I could give this as an answer, but it seems weird.